# Confusion about syntax error reported by JSLint

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string-formatting, jslint

So I'm working on [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ruFrp/12/) and I'm getting errors when I run jslint on the code... Can anyone provide the fix for this? I just don't know what to do. To see the error messages, follow my link and click "JSLint".

EDIT: If anyone's curious, [here's it working.](http://jsfiddle.net/ruFrp/15/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put a `\` before the `{` and `}` in your regex pattern. This is known as `escaping`.
http://jsfiddle.net/ruFrp/13/